# How to output positive minimum number in do while loop?

Tags: c++

The program outputs a minimum negative number when I need to output a positive minimum number. Negative number is ending data entry.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int totalNumber, max, min, score = 0, sum = 0;
float avrg;
 do {
     sum = sum + score;
     cout << "Enter score " << ++totalNumber <<": ";
     cin >> score;
         if (score < min) {
         min = score;
      }
      if (score > max){
         max = score;
      }
  }
  while(score >= 0);
  totalNumber -= 1;
  avrg = sum / totalNumber;
  cout << " You entered " << totalNumber << " scores" <<endl;
  cout << " Maximum score = " << max << endl;
  cout << " Minimum score = " << min << endl;
  cout << " Average score = " << avrg << endl;
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You need use unsigned int if you want a positive integer, Z+

Comment: `int max, min` Those are nowhere initialized. Also, it is ill advised to use names used by `std`.

Comment: No need to `sum = sum + score;` BEFORE the value of `score` is read...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to actually *ask*  a question.

Comment: You have to initialise totalNumber = 0, min = MAX_INT, max = MIN_INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. All you needed to do was to make sure that the number was not less than 0 and that if it is the first number inputted, that should become min immediately.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int totalNumber = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int score = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    float avrg;
    do 
    {
        sum = sum + score;
        cout << "Enter score " << ++totalNumber <<": ";
        cin >> score;
        if (totalNumber == 1)
        {
            min = score;
        }
        else if ((score < min) && (score > 0))
        {
            min = score;
        }
        else if (score > max)
        {
            max = score;
        }
    }
    while(score >= 0);
    totalNumber -= 1;
    avrg = sum / totalNumber;
    cout << " You entered " << totalNumber << " scores" <<endl;
    cout << " Maximum score = " << max << endl;
    cout << " Minimum score = " << min << endl;
    cout << " Average score = " << avrg << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the the points addressed in comments, I think you should break out of the loop when you receive a negative value. And add sum value after reading `score`. Here is how your modified loop would look like:

```cpp
do {
    cout << "Enter score " << ++totalNumber <<": ";
    cin >> score;
    sum = sum + score;
    if (score < 0) { // Negative value; Exit from loop
        cout << "exiting..." << endl;
        break;
    }
    if (score < min) {
        min = score;
    }
    if (score > max){
        max = score;
    }
} while(score >= 0);
```

When I tried this, it seemed to be working as expected:

```
src : $ g++ posititveminimum.cpp 
src : $ ./a.out 
Enter score 1: 48
Enter score 2: 60
Enter score 3: 78
Enter score 4: 91
Enter score 5: 67
Enter score 6: -1
 You entered 5 scores
 Maximum score = 91
 Minimum score = 48
 Average score = 68
```